# MariaDB User procedure loops endlessly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have the following stored procedure to calculate running averages. However when called, it runs forever.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE run_avg(date_start DATE,date_end DATE,pol_id  TINYINT,sta_id TINYINT)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL

BEGIN

TRUNCATE average_table;

WHILE date_start <= date_end DO

INSERT INTO average_table(value_avg)
SELECT AVG(a.value) as val
FROM (SELECT value FROM obs_all_unik
    WHERE start_time >=date_start
      AND start_time < date_start + INTERVAL 8  HOUR
      AND polutant_id=pol_id
      AND station_id=sta_id) AS a;

SET date_start = date_start + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
END WHILE;

END;//

delimiter ;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endless loop was due to a wrong definition of date_start as DATE. Since I tried to increment by hours it was returning one and the same value. I changed it to TIMESTAMP and now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(station_id, polution_id, start_date)
```

would help performance.

It seems wrong to insert just the averages into the table without also inserting these values:  `station_id, polution_id, start_date`.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain the problem clearly. The procedure goes into an endless loop writing into the table only the first value and never advancing to calculate the second average. Until I realize there was a problem, it has written about 45000 times the first value and I had to kill the query.

Comment: average_table is just a place to temporary store the numbers. I don't see a point to add station_id, polution_id, start_date a thousand or more times.

Comment: But if you have lots of rows in `average_table`, which is which?

Comment: Since the moving averages are calculated and stored in a specific order I only need the timestamp to know the order of numbers. But that is not the point here. Please, if you can see my mistake which makes the procedure into an endless loop just point it out.

Comment: But you are not including the timestamp in the list.  SQL is free to shuffle the rows; do not trust that the "first" row will be the "first" row.

Comment: Right now, SQL is writing one and the same value in every row and I pretty much don't give a query if they are shuffled.